# How i should design database ER-Diagram for this problem

Tags: database

i have some specific question to solve but i can not think.

I have 5-6 statements that I need to store in my database. This system like a news feeds.

1. Statement 1 : **A** installed this website.
2. Statement 2 : **A** added **store R** in **provinceX**
3. Statement 3 : **B** reviewed **store R**
4. Statement 4 : **A** edited **store R**
5. Statement 5 : **A** added **product P** in **product_category1**
6. Statement 6 : **B** review **product P**

Note that bold is dynamic data such as A, B is some preson's name, store R is store'name that person add.

In my idea, i have

- person_table(id, name, age, ...)
- store_table(sid, store_name, province_id, ...)
- product_table(pid, product_name, ...)

and how about feed_table??

How I design database to store this data. and How i query this data to view.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this kind of problem:

1. You design your tables in such a way that you have no repetition of information. Basically the feed you're interested in can be constructed from the existing tables in a performant manner; or
2. You repeat certain data to make your feed easier to implement.

Personally I would probably go for (2) and have a new table:

- Feed: id, person_id, store_id, action_id, province_id, product_category_id

with the last two fields being optional, based on the action (review, edit, add, etc).

Purists will argue that repeated data is bad (certainly normal-form seeks to factor it out) but in the real world database schemas do this all the time for performance reasons.

Think about it this way: what do you spend most of your time doing in your application?

1. Viewing the feed (reading); or
2. Doing actions (writing).

If it's (1), which I suspect it is, then a feed table makes sense. You typically want to optimize for reads not writes as writes occur far less often.

Comment: +1: this is te likely approach I would take - you'll need a product_id field too.

Comment: @Giffary `action_id` just represents the action (edit, add, review). You could use plain text for this or the actions could be listed in another table, hence `action_id` (as a foreign key into an action table). It's notional.